# DiscordAPIError: Maximum number of application commands reached (100)

Tags: discord, command, slash

I'm currently creating a Discord bot that has 112 commands and I'm receiving this error:

[Error code: 30034](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCSUu.png)

[Discord's daily command limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqlGi.png)

On Discords Developer Portal's Documentation, it states that "There is a global rate limit of 200 application command creates per day, per guild".

So my question is: Is my bot currently limited to creating new commands through a daily limit? Do I just have to simply wait it out?

Or is my bot unable to create anymore slash commands.

I'm attempting to create a Discord bot that will eventually exceed 200+ commands.

Comment: How many `CHAT_INPUT` commands do you have?

Comment: And a [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73582680/14945696).

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that Discord only allows:

- 100 global CHAT_INPUT commands
- 5 global USER commands
- 5 global MESSAGE commands

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).